# Como posso classificar um teste, release ou feature?

Tags: tdd, git-flow

Se eu crio um teste em algo que já existe, isso entra como release ou feature em um fluxo do git-flow? até por que um teste não deixa de ser uma melhoria mas também não deixa de ser algo novo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considerando a separação como abaixo:

1. **feature branches**: Contém códigos que podem ou não ser incluídos na próxima release, o merge das features é realizado na **branch develop**
2. **develop branch**: Contém features que serão disponibilizadas na próxima **release**
3. **master branch**: Contém o código da **release atual** partindo da **branch develop**, que entrará em produção
4. **hotfix branches:** Partem da **branch master** ou da branch que equivale a versão atual em produção, utilizada para um reparo imediato em produção

Não existe problema em tratar apenas o desenvolvimento de um teste como uma **feature**, você não possui a necessidade imediata de incluí-lo em produção (hotfix).

Seguindo o fluxo normal, sua alteração entraria como **feature -> develop -> master**. Em alguns casos isto se torna verboso, caso seja pontual e de comum acordo entre o time, você pode enviá-lo para a **develop** diretamente.

Recomendo a leitura do fluxo [aqui](https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/)